# How to jump to the Android implementation source file in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

in Android Studio (2.2 Preview 2), I have the sdk sources attached and I can also jump to the interfaces of android sources: e.g. when I <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-click on `SharedPreferences`, the file `~/Android/Sdk/sources/android-23/android/content/SharedPreferences.java` is opened.

But now I also want to jump to the implementation of this interface - or a member function e.g. `getFloat()`

How can this be done?

notes:

- clicking <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> only show the error `no implementations found`
- the relevant file `SharedPreferencesImpl.java` exists in the location where I expect it: `~/Android/Sdk/sources/android-23/android/app`
- the `compileSdkVersion` is set to 23 in my `build.gradle` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to easily get me to the implementation file:

- Set the cursor to the interface-name `SharedPreferences`
- Open the `Find Usages` dialogue (e.g. press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>7</kbd>). In the `Scope` box select `Project and Libraries`.
- Click the `Find` button and the SharedPreferencesImpl class will show up in `Found usages` (under the *Android API 23 Platform* node)

Comment: You could also just Press Shift + N +N and Enter SharedPreferencesimpl this worked for me

Comment: yes, but the use-case is when I don't know which classes implement the interface.Thus I want to search for all implementations which can usually be done easily via `Navigate - Implementation(s)` - but in this case it does not work: see the answer of mrkernelpanic

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I found the solution. The implementation class signature looks the following:

```
final class SharedPreferencesImpl implements SharedPreferences {
```

This is the default access modifier and means that it is only visible in the current package android.app. But your interface is defined in another package android.content thats why Android Studio cannot find the implementation.

But even If you click through your "External Libraries" in Android Studio of your project you cannot see the android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl class ...

Comment: thanks - that was helpful. It does indeed work for other public implementations.